# AWS separate projects among multiple users

Tags: amazon-iam

I am new to AWS and I am wondering if there is a way to disable or hide projects based on IAM accounts, 
eg. Let say multiple users develop 2 apps on same AWS account but don't want to share the resources (apis, lambda functions, s3 buckets etc.). Each user will see the resources of his own project not the other. They all have access to these resources but need to block irrelevant project works.

Im not sure this is the correct place to ask this question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit write access to a function (invoke/update/delete etc.) by name using IAM policies. As for read access, I’m not sure why you’d need to but you can’t really restrict it 100% as the ListFunctions action can only be scoped to resource * so they’ll always be able to “see” other functions in the list functions view unless you keep them in separate regions and restrict users to certain regions (not a great idea though).

If you truly need this level of isolation, just create another AWS account and keep the the applications in their own account. For consolidated billing just use AWS Organizations

Comment: yes, AWS Organizations is the one I was looking for